Why MemoryPool is slower when allocate small size data in C++
I wrote the MemoryPool test code as below, and the MemoryPool allocates memory faster only when the fieldSize is set to 10000 or more. Why is it slower when allocating memory with smaller sizes?
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
#include <mutex>
#include <memory>

const int fieldSize = 10000; // When it is more than 10000, allocation with MemoryPool is faster.
const int numThreads = 1;
const int numObjectInterval = 1000000;

struct MemoryPoolTest {
    int temp{};
    char data[fieldSize]{};

    MemoryPoolTest(int i = 0) {
        temp = i;
    }
};

template<typename T>
class SimpleMemoryPool {
public:
    SimpleMemoryPool() = default;

    SimpleMemoryPool(const SimpleMemoryPool &) = delete;

    SimpleMemoryPool &operator=(const SimpleMemoryPool &) = delete;

    template<typename... Args>
    T *allocate(Args &&... args) {
        std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(mutex_);
        if (!pool_.empty()) {
            T *obj = pool_.top();
            pool_.pop();
            return obj;
        }
        return new T(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    }

    void deallocate(T *obj) {
        std::lock_guard<std::recursive_mutex> lock(mutex_);
        pool_.push(obj);
    }

private:
    std::stack<T *> pool_;
    std::recursive_mutex mutex_;
};

void TestAllocateWithoutPool(int numObjects) {
    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < numObjects; ++i) {
        MemoryPoolTest *obj = new MemoryPoolTest(i);
        obj->temp = i;
        delete obj;
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> duration = end - start;
    std::cout << "numObjects Count =  " << numObjects << ", Time taken without memory pool: " << duration.count()
              << " seconds\n";
}

SimpleMemoryPool<MemoryPoolTest> pool;

void TestAllocateWithMemoryPool(int numObjects) {

    auto start = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    for (int i = 0; i < numObjects; ++i) {
        MemoryPoolTest *obj = pool.allocate(i);
        obj->temp = i;
        pool.deallocate(obj);
    }
    auto end = std::chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
    std::chrono::duration<double> duration = end - start;
    std::cout << "numObjects Count =  " << numObjects << ", Time taken with memory pool: " << duration.count()
              << " seconds\n";
}

void TestAllocateWithoutPoolByThread() {
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::cout << "\nTesting without memory pool:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
        threads.emplace_back(TestAllocateWithoutPool, numObjectInterval * (i + 1));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
        threads[i].join();
    }
}

void TestAllocateWithPoolByThread() {
    std::vector<std::thread> threads;
    std::cout << "\nTesting with memory pool:\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
        threads.emplace_back(TestAllocateWithMemoryPool, numObjectInterval * (i + 1));
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < numThreads; i++) {
        threads[i].join();
    }
    threads.clear();
}

int main() {
    TestAllocateWithoutPoolByThread();

    // first test with MemoryPool (MemoryPool is not full)
    TestAllocateWithPoolByThread();

    // first test with MemoryPool (MemoryPool is full now, it should be faster than test without MemoryPool)
    TestAllocateWithPoolByThread();

    TestAllocateWithoutPoolByThread();
    return 0;
}

When I set the fieldSize 10000, result is as below.
Testing without memory pool:
numObjects Count =  1000000, Time taken without memory pool: 0.0655205 seconds

Testing with memory pool:
numObjects Count =  1000000, Time taken with memory pool: 0.0595625 seconds

Testing with memory pool:
numObjects Count =  1000000, Time taken with memory pool: 0.0636256 seconds

Testing without memory pool:
numObjects Count =  1000000, Time taken without memory pool: 0.0674414 seconds


When I set the fieldSize 1000, result is as below.
Testing without memory pool:
numObjects Count =  1000000, Time taken without memory pool: 0.0225407 seconds

Testing with memory pool:
numObjects Count =  1000000, Time taken with memory pool: 0.0604793 seconds

Testing with memory pool:
numObjects Count =  1000000, Time taken with memory pool: 0.0600341 seconds

Testing without memory pool:
numObjects Count =  1000000, Time taken without memory pool: 0.0246731 seconds

I don't know why this result came out.
I am looking forward to seeing your wise answers.
Thank you for reading.

What is ObjectPool?

ObjectPool is a class that uses templates to allow each class to use a MemoryPool that fits its size.
@kiner_shah

Please don't post images of text. Copy-paste text as text into your questions. Something you really should know by now. And without a [mre] it's almost impossible to help you.

You could try your test with a different pool implementation (say from Boost), to show that the problem is your pool, not pools in general. With threads, the details are super important, like having one pool per thread vs a global, mutex-protected pool (or something lock-free).

Thanks for taking the time to write a well thought out question. It is going to be difficult to answer without more information in the pool in question. Marc’s suggestion is a good one. You may also want to make a simpler pool that you are able to share and see it it still happens - it’ll be hard to say without seeing the details of the pool.

I would also suggest using a benchmark suite like google benchmark, as it’s quite a hard thing to get right - you will hopefully get more accurate data that way.

I erased images.
Thank you for letting me know.
@Someprogrammerdude

Also I have edited my question.
I would be really glad if you see it again.
@OMGtechy

@MarcGlisse
I edited my question.
Thank you for your reply.

@DoyoHntr -- Why is it slower when allocating memory with smaller sizes? -- I looked at your question, and I do not see what settings you used to build the application.  Any question that has to do with the performance of a C++ application must be accompanied by the build settings you used to build the application.  The most important of these settings are the optimization levels used.  If you are timing a "debug" or unoptimized build, then the timings you are showing are meaningless.

If you use a profiler or other tool to analyze the parallel performance of your code, it is likely to tell you that most of the time is spent in the (contended) mutex, whereas malloc has a fast path that avoids a mutex in most cases. (gcc/clang optimize your withoutpool function to nothing)
